# How to Retrive Different Bean class Objects from HashMap which was created in Spring Controller and added to Model Object

Tags: java, spring, jsp, hashmap, jstl

I am new to spring and i need the help.

**My Work towards the problem
steps**

1:Created a controller and i created 5 Bean  class objects in controller

2:Created HashMap.

3:Added the bean class objects to HashMap.

4:Added the HashMap to Model Object.

5:In Jsp i want to retrieve bean class objects and print the bean class property values in jsp (Success view).

```
      public class SocialMediaContoller{//step1

//step2
    TwitterBean tb=new sampleA();

    GoogleBean gb=new GoogleBean();

    YouTubeBean yb=new YouTubeBean();

    InstagramBean ib=new InstagramBean();

    FaceBookBean fb=new FaceBookBean();


//step3  
        Map<String,Object> socialmedia=new HashMap<String,Object>();
        socialmedia.put("twittermetrics",tb);
        socialmedia.put("googleplusmetrics",gb);
        socialmedia.put("instagrammetrics",ib);
        socialmedia.put("youtubemetrics",yb);
        socialmedia.put("facebookmetrics",fb);

    //spe4
    return "view/socialmedia/SocialMediaSuccess"; 
    }
```

InSuccessJSP
step6:
I want to display the values of bean class properties 
My code is:

```
 <div id="twitter">
    <div id="twitterMetrics">
    <p><b>Twitter Profile Analysis</b></p>
     <table id="twitterTable">
    <tr>
    <td><b>Followers</b></td>
    <td><c:out value="${tb.followers}" /></td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
    </table>
<table id="googleTable">
    <tr>
    <td><b>Followers</b></td>
    <td><c:out value="${gb.followers}" /></td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
    </table>
<table id="youtubeTable">
    <tr>
    <td><b>Followers</b></td>
    <td><c:out value="${yb.views}" /></td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
    </table>
<table id="instagarmTable">
    <tr>
    <td><b>Followers</b></td>
    <td><c:out value="${ib.followers}" /></td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>

    </div>
```

same for remaining objects

in JSP

Finally I Need Help/Code at **(Step6)To retrieve elements from MapObject(i.e socialmedia)From Model Object in JSP success page**

Answer (score 0):

The Model object itself represents a Map, so creating another Map to inject into Model is redundant. Instead just add your beans directly to Model e.g. model.addAttribute("twittermetrics",tb). In the JSP you can directly refer to the Model keys.

Comment: Thanks Zoostar for your response,I adding the reference Objects in **different conditions/cases(Post & Get method's also)**,In all cases if i added them to MODEL Object ,because of the the size of CODE increases

Answer (score 0):

Currently your controller is returning String. For retrieving elements from MapObject(i.e socialmedia) you need to return ModelAndView. Please find below the code snippet.

**Controller**

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/getSocialMediaData")
        public ModelAndView getSocialMediaData() throws SystemException, BusinessException{
    private ModelMap map = new ModelMap();  
                TwitterBean tb=new sampleA();
                GoogleBean gb=new GoogleBean();
                YouTubeBean yb=new YouTubeBean();
                InstagramBean ib=new InstagramBean();
                FaceBookBean fb=new FaceBookBean();
                map.addAttribute("twittermetrics",tb);
                map.addAttribute("googleplusmetrics",gb);
                map.addAttribute("instagrammetrics",ib);
                map.addAttribute("youtubemetrics",yb);
                map.addAttribute("facebookmetrics",fb);
      return new ModelAndView("view/socialmedia/SocialMediaSuccess",map);
}
```

**Success JSP**

```
<div id="twitter">
   <div id="twitterMetrics">
    <p><b>Twitter Profile Analysis</b></p>
     <table id="twitterTable">
    <tr>
    <td><b>Followers</b></td>
    <td><c:out value="${twittermetrics.followers}" /></td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
</table>
<table id="googleTable">
    <tr>
    <td><b>Followers</b></td>
    <td><c:out value="${googleplusmetrics.followers}" /></td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
 </table>
<table id="youtubeTable">
    <tr>
    <td><b>Followers</b></td>
    <td><c:out value="${youtubemetrics.views}" /></td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
 </table>
<table id="instagarmTable">
    <tr>
    <td><b>Followers</b></td>
    <td><c:out value="${instagrammetrics.followers}" /></td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Sunil fr your code ,it is correct,but i got it before only

Comment: ohk great but can we consider the answer as correct for your question?